# Primitive derived operations and combinators in EDSL:s

Tags: haskell, dsl

I recently flunked an exam, mostly because of a EDSL question. I did not grasp these concepts so I think thats why I failed. I think my teachers explanation was to abstract for me to understand, so I wonder if someone could explain it more clearly.

I wonder if someone could explain briefly what the components of a EDSL is, and what characterize them. In our course we have gone through Shallow and Deep Embedding of a DSL and looked at the following building blocks for a DSL:

1. Constructor functions
2. Combinators (primitive and derived)
3. Run functions

I think contructor and run functions are more self-explanatory, so Im more interested to understand what makes a Combinator derived or primitive. It doesn´t hurt if someone will explain the other concepts. Here is an example from our lectures for reference. Its a shallow implemenation of a DSL for creating signals:

```
module Signal.Shallow
( Time
-- | the 'Signal' type is abstract
, Signal  
-- * Smart constructors
, constS, timeS
-- * Combinators
, ($$), mapT
-- * Derived operation
, mapS
-- * Run function
, sample
) where

-- * Smart constructors
constS :: a -> Signal a
timeS  ::      Signal Time
-- * Combinators
($$)   :: Signal (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
mapT   :: (Time -> Time)  -> Signal a -> Signal a
-- * Derived operation
mapS   :: (a -> b)        -> Signal a -> Signal b
-- * Run function
sample :: Signal a -> Time -> a  

type Time = Double
newtype Signal a = Sig {unSig :: Time -> a}

-- | The constant signal.
constS x = Sig (const x)

-- | The time signal
timeS = Sig id

-- | Function application lifted to signals.
fs $$ xs = Sig (\t -> unSig fs t  (unSig xs t))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primitive combinator is one that's built into the DSL, defined in the base language (ie Haskell). DSLs are often built around an **abstract type**—a type whose implementation is hidden to the end-user. It's completely opaque. The primitive combinators, presented by the language, are the ones that need to know how the abstraction is actually implemented to work.

A derived combinator, on the other hand, can be implemented in terms of other combinators already in the DSL. It *does not* need to know anything about the abstract types. In other words, a derived combinator is one *you could have written yourself*.

This is very similar to the idea of primitive types in Haskell itself. For example, you can't implement `Int` or the `Int` operations like `+` yourself. These require things built into the compiler to work because numbers are treated specially. On the other hand, `Bool` is *not* primitive; you could write it as a library.

```
data Bool = True | False -- ... you can't do this for Int!
```

"Primitive" and "derived" for DSLs is the same idea except the compiler is actually your Haskell library.

In your example, `Signal` is an abstract type. It's implemented as a function `Time -> a`, but that information is *not* exported from the module. In the future, you (as the author of the DSL) are free to change how `Signal` is implemented. (And, in fact, you'd really want to: this is not an efficient representation and using `Double` for time is finicky.)

A function like `$$` is primitive because it depends on knowing that `Signal` is `Time -> a`. When you change the representation of `Signal`, you'll have to rewrite `$$`. Moreover, a user of your library wouldn't be able to implement `$$` themselves.

On the other hand, `mapS` is a derived operation because it could be written entirely in terms of the other things you're exporting. It does not need to know anything special about `Signal` and could even be written by one of the users of the library. The implementation could look something like:

```
mapS f signal = constS f $$ signal
```

Note how it uses `constS` and `$$`, but never unwraps `signal`. The knowledge of *how* to unwrap signal is hidden entirely in those two functions. `mapS` is "derived" because it is written just in your DSL without needing anything below your level of abstraction. When you change the implementation of `Signal`, `mapS` will still work as-is: you just need to update `constS` and `$$` properly and you get `mapS` for free.

So: primitive combinators are ones which are built directly into your language and need to know about its internal implementation details. Derived combinators are written purely *in terms* of your language and do not depend on any of these internal details. They're just convenience functions which could have just as easily been written by the end-user of your library.